# Put 2 function in one onClick with react, one of them should be a callback

Tags: reactjs, onclick, parent-child, buttonclick

I want to put put 2 function then I click on updateButton first a function the second one a callback.

I want one of them in this structure onClick={}
and the second one in this structure onClick={() => }

How should I do it ?

```
const handleModification = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setToogleUpdatePost((toogleUpdatePost) => !toogleUpdatePost);
  };

      const data = "child to parent from update to parent";
    
    return(
    {authCtx.userId === props.item.item.userId ? (
              // <Button className="updateButton" onClickProps={handleModification}>
              <Button
                className="updateButton"
                onClickProps={() => props.childToParent(data)}
              >
       )
```

Of course this code above there is an error
I provide more information so that you can better understand what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Why don't you do this?
<Button
      className="updateButton"
      onClickProps={(e) => {
                             props.childToParent(data); 
                             handleModification(e);
                          }}
/>